# youtube: use youtube player in website

Tags: youtube

I am not sure , But is there any way to use YouTube video player for playing .flv file , which are stored in my own server.

any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so, you can only use it to play content hosted on their site, but there are plenty of other flash players around. [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) is a common one, and there are loads more if you Google.

Comment: Flowplayer is also very nice.

Comment: Thanks buddy , It is relay helpful

Answer (score 2):

No.

You would have to upload the files to Youtube to use their player (which you can embed)

How ever there are many Youtube-like players (which will play .flv files on your own server), for example:

- [flvplayer](http://code.google.com/p/flvplayer/)
- [FPlayer](http://as3flvplayer.sourceforge.net/)
- [BitGravity](http://player.bitgravity.com/6/simple/source.php)
- [JW FLV Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/)
- [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but there are other options available that are very very similar.

Check out the JW Player [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

If you don't mind targetting just cutting-edge browsers though, you could make use of the HTML5 <video> tags:

```
 <video src="path/to/your/video">Your browser doesn't support this.</video>
```

I know the beta versions of FF3.5 support this, but it is a new feature that's not widely supported yet.

Otherwise, use something like FlowPlayer as suggested in other responses.

Comment: Ya ! I have seen that , But I want something without any LOGO or something like logo.

Comment: <video> tags Will enhance HTML by far !

Answer (score 0):

Why not just upload the video to YouTube and embed the player?

Comment: actually ,  I have to do it for multiple videos